# Strange output with console.log(5)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the simplest chrome extension which contains a content javascript (nothing else):

```
script="\
c=0;\
(function f() {\
    if (++c>20) return;\
    console.log(5);\
    setTimeout(f, 500);\
})();\
";
scriptBlock = document.createElement('script');
scriptBlock.type = 'text/javascript';
scriptBlock.appendChild(document.createTextNode(script));
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptBlock);
```

This simply injects a small piece of js into the head element.
In mail.google.com, the console output is 4 fives followed by sixteen `Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.`Every other site displays simply 20 fives.

Can anyone explain this behaviour please?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a global variable in your script. If a script in the page uses a global variable with the same name, it will change the value in the variable, and your script will show that value instead.

Comment: which global variable - c? the code above is the complete unchanged content script

Comment: While that's true, it seems the counter is working (the OP describes 20 "pieces" of output), and even if it was broken, how does that explain the MIME-type message? `c` would have to be a very very strange host object for that to all make sense.

Comment: @jadegem: Yes, *c* is the global variable. @davin: You have a point there... If the number of messages is not a coincidence, then the only possible reason would be that `console.log` is redefined...

Comment: changed c to c2634, and I still have the problem

Answer (score 1):

As @Guffa said, your global variable may be overwritten. Including it inside the closure will ensure it will be accessed by your code only.

```
(function () {
    var c = 0;

    setTimeout(function f() {
        if (++c > 20) return;

        console.log(5);

        setTimeout(f, 500);
    }, 500);
}());
```

Comment: I did that, copy and paste from your code. The problem is even worse, now displays only twice 5 and 18 ... Try it yourself

Comment: @jadegem I did, works fine. Albeit, I only tested it in the console. Note, though, that Chrome compacts duplicate console output onto a single line with a count number to the left.

Comment: switched off my mountains theme and it works fine now. Try using mountains theme. Wonder what it could be

Comment: was nothing to do with the theme - it's just that on settings it works, on inbox doesn't work. but my other gmail account is fine